# How can I use a specific keyboard layout from Windows 10?

Tags: keyboard

For my job, I am forced to use a Mac. The interface is quite nice, but the keyboard is unbearable. I am used to the Canadian French (CAFR) keyboard layout from Windows. However, it is not available in MacOS.

I was wondering if there was a way to important the keyboard easily without having to map all the letters manually (with Karabiner or Ukulele).

Do you have an idea on how to import a keyboard layout from Windows to Mac?

[image]

Comment: Why not start from the Mac's CaFr layout & mod the few keys that changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find this layout for MacOS [here](https://github.com/ergosteur/cf-keylayout).

There is definitely no way to import Windows keyboard layouts to Mac, or vice versa.